# I can't make my x axis reactive using ggplot in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

For simplicity I will only include the parts of the code that I am having issues with. This code pulls a large data set from a data base and creates tabs with different analyses. I am having issues with making my x variable reactive for ggplot graphs. If I define the x variable inside aes() the plot shows up fine but once I create a reactive input that substitutes my variable then ggplot has troubles defining the x variable. The variables I want to be able to switch are: "assay_plate_label" and "assay_read_on" from my data set.

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)


shinyUI(fluidPage(
# Header or Title Panel 
titlePanel(title = h4("HTS QC analysis", align="center")),
sidebarLayout(
# Sidebar panel
sidebarPanel(

  numericInput("pg_number", "Plate Group", 4552),
  actionButton('process', 'Process Plate Group Data')

),


# Main Panel
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(type="tab", 
tabPanel("Box Plot All", 
                       selectInput('x_axis', "Choose the X axis", choices= c("Assay Plate Label"= "assay_plate_label", "Assay Date"= "assay_read_on")),
                       plotOutput("deviation"))


    )

   )

  )
) 
)
```

server.r

```
 shinyServer(function(input, output){



  x_label <- reactive({
  switch(input$x_axis,
         "assay_plate_label" = assay_plate_label,
         "assay_read_on"=  assay_read_on)
 })



  read.csv("table_na")
 [Here is a sample of the data with the variables I use in this plot ][1]




 output$deviation <- renderPlot({


  table_na$assay_plate_label <- as.character(table_na$assay_plate_label)
  ggplot(table_na, aes(x_label(), y=raw_assay_value, group=as.character(x_label()))) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 3, vjust= 0)) +
    xlab("Plate Label")+
    ylab(table_na$plate_type_name)+
    geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "red", outlier.size= 1.5)+
    ggtitle("All Plates Box Plot")


})
 })



 }
 )
```

I had to cut down on most of the unnecessary code to make it understandable, but the code that relates to the problem it self is all here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to know without being able to run the code, but try aes_string instead of aes.

Comment: Perhaps you could upvote the answer since that is the whole point of the site.